How to enforce a state only if a minon has SELinux installed?
I have code that installs a custom selinux module. In my fleet of minions there's Fedora-based systems (with SELinux installed) and Debian-based ones (without SELinux ). On the latter the module/installing state should not be used and I am thus looking for a way of retrieving a neat answer to the question "is SELinux  installed on this system?" (NOT "is SELinux  enforcing on this system?") to use in a corresponding jinja2 if clause.
Attempts that have me despairing are:

there appears to be no state in Salt querying whether a given binary is on the $PATH - checking for sestatus is what I was after here.
salt.states.selinux is not available on systems devoid of SELinux, so its functionality does not help.
I could not find any Salt functionality to query for the local availability of something like salt.states.selinux (see above) either.
Something like
- unless: - rpm -q libselinux

(from this answer) also does not work, as rpm is Fedora specific...
Checking for absence of /etc/selinux also is not an option, as the Debian systems actually have that.

Any hint on how to go about this is appreciated.

You could also use the os grain to conditionally execute specific states. E.g. if grains['os'] == 'Fedora'.

Following this hint, I ended up doing:
{% if salt['pkg.version']('libselinux') %}
...
{% endif %}

Not what I would call neat and using somewhat convoluted logic, but it appears to do the trick.

If selinux is installed, then a grain is available:
{% if 'selinux' in grains %}

# stuff that's only included if selinux is available

{% endif %}

You can also use that grain for minion targeting:
base:
  'selinux:*':
    - match: grain
    - my_states.for_selinux_only


In general, you can also check whether a module has been loaded:
{% if 'selinux.getconfig' in salt %}

Whether an executable is on the PATH:
{% if 'sestatus' | which %}

Whether a package is installed (which also works in an onlyif parameter):
{% if salt['pkg.version']('libselinux') %}


The {% if 'selinux.getconfig' in salt %}bit actually does not work for me. This possibly queries the salsetup in the master rather than the minion. Anyway. Will fall back on the minion targeting/grain.

No, templates render on the minion. The module may have additional requirements to be loaded, e.g. a relevant python package.

@balin there's also a which Jinja filter, which I've just added an example for.
